# What is the format specification for Avidyne R9 flight data?

Tags: avionics, flight-data-recorder, software

The Avidyne R9 records flight data five times per second and can [export it for later analysis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7GwjMk6HuI).

I'm interested in parsing this data and exporting it to Google Earth / X-Plane for visualization.  [Cirrusreports](http://www.cirrusreports.com) already does this, so I know it's possible.  It would be easier, though, if there was a spec already out there.

**Is there a specification for the Avidyne R9 flight data file format available, preferably online?**

Comment: Can you post a sample file? I can take a peek and see if it's in any of the industry-standard formats I've encountered. Nothing jumped out at me from a quick Google search. (I analyze / reverse engineer data like this all the time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section 12-4 of the [Release 9 Pilot's Guide](http://dealers.avidyne.com/files/downloads/600-00190-000.pdf), data logs are saved as a simple .csv file that can imported into any spreadsheet software (like Microsoft Excel) for analysis.

There are many free tools that can covert Excel files to KML for Google Earth, ie: http://www.earthpoint.us/exceltokml.aspx